# Why adjugate matrix 2x2 is different from 3x3 and others?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've understand the simple way of calculating the adjugate matrix.

In short:

1). We need to calculate all cofactors:

Using the next formula: [$A_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j} M_{ij}$](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/1/a/a1ada4409e7e964f57f4c28a8e160b0e.png)

2). Transpose it.

It's also can be read from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

> In linear algebra, the adjugate, classical adjoint, or adjunct of a
>   square matrix is the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

If to view examples, such short algorithm is correct for squared matrices 3x3 and larger...

But, for 2x2 is just a rule:

```
M = [ a b ]
    [ c d ]

adj( M ) = [  d -b ]
           [ -c  a ]
```

What do I dislike?

I dislike that, because it's some kind of prayer. And many forums in web are saying:

> Just remember it? right?

Damn! People, it's a MATH, it's not some humanity science like history. It's A MATH, math consists of logic and explanation as any other technical stuff.

I don't want just to remember stupidly some formula, I want understand why is exactly using such adjugate calculation especially for matrix 2x2?

I don't understand the next... For the matrix 3x3 we calculate all cofactors and then transpose it, for e.g.:

```
Original:
1   2   3
2   5   4
5   2   3

Cofactor matrix:
  7  14 -21
  0 -12  8
 -7   2  1

Transposed cofactor matrix:
  7   0 -7
 14 -12  2
-21   8  1
```

As you can see the transpose process for 3x3 didn't exchange the value a11 and a33, but why there is such an exchange for 2x3 matrix? I don't understand... I want to get logical explanation, not just a strict prayer.

I want to hear explanation `why?` and such explanation must be logical.

Comment: The $2\times 2$ rule is just a particular case of the general definition. The cofactors of a $2\times 2$-matrix are $\pm$ determinants of $1 \times 1$-matrices, and the determinant of a $1\times 1$-matrix is its unique entry.

Comment: Try calculating the cofactor matrix of a $2 \times 2$ matrix.  What happens?

Comment: It's also ridiculous to expect to do mathematics without remembering some convenient special cases: if you can't recall anything immediately, you lose your train of thought all the time. You remember the quadratic formula, and the derivative of $x^n$ and $\sin{x}$, don't you? But they're just weird special cases of more general formulae.

Answer (score 7):

Consider what happens when you're getting the matrix of minors for a $3\times 3$: You are getting the value for the $a_{ij}$ element by calculating the determinant of the non $i,j$ rows (I won't go through this since, judging by your question, you know how to do this already).

Now consider the same logic applied to a $2\times 2$ matrix: Do the same steps, except instead of having a $2\times 2$ matrix to calculate the determinant from, you have a $1\times 1$. In this case, the determinant is the single element in that matrix. From this, you can do the same steps as you would for a $3\times 3$.

I'll run through an example here (I'll compare with a $3\times 3$ matrix since that's the simplest matrix where these rules are first introduced):

Matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$.

Matrix of minors $= \begin{bmatrix} d & c\\ b & a\end{bmatrix}$ - for element $(1,1)$ (i.e. $a$), "cover" row $1$ and column $1$ and you're left with $d$ so that equals the determinant for that element for the matrix of minors (as with a $3\times 3$).

Cofactor matrix, $C = \begin{bmatrix} d & -c\\ -b & a\end{bmatrix}$ - exact same as for a $3\times 3$.

$\operatorname{adj}A = C^T = \begin{bmatrix} d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$ - again, exact same as for a $3\times 3$.

This is where you get the "Just remember it" from. It follows the exact same steps as for any $n\times n$ matrix.

Then you calculate $A^{-1}$ as usual: $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A}\operatorname{adj}A$.

Hope this helps.